# How to remove space between labels in chartjs doughnut in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have a chart as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJUW6.png)

I want to remove spaces between labels
below is my code

```
    import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2"
import { Chart, ArcElement } from "chart.js"
import { useRef } from "react"
import { DoughnutComponentProps } from "../../../types/components/DoughnutComponentProps"

const DoughnutComponent = ({
    datasets,
    borderRadius,
    cutoutPercentage,
    height,
    width,
}: DoughnutComponentProps) => {
    const data = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        datasets: datasets,
    }
    const chartRef = useRef(null)
    Chart.register(ArcElement)
    const chartOptions = {
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
        cutoutPercentage: cutoutPercentage,
        hover: {
            mode: null,
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    padding: 100,
                },
            },
        },
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Doughnut
                data={data}
                options={chartOptions}
                ref={chartRef}
                height={height}
                width={width}
            />
        </>
    )
}
export default DoughnutComponent
```

I have tried adding negative padding and so on. This is my first time using chartJs.